# Strange error - bat file doesn't run

Tags: windows, path, batch-file, javac

I run javac from command line in windows(cmd.exe) - it works fine. But when I'm trying to run the bat file with javac test.java from the same directory, it gives an error "javac is not external or internal command..."

Comment: Did you use the full path of the javac command?

Comment: why should I if I have it in the PATH variable?

Comment: Doesn't look to me as if the context in which your .bat runs has it configured that way.

Comment: Try writing a batch file with the following command:

echo %PATH%

Does it print out ok?

Comment: it doesn't print path to javac. I'm confused

Comment: @Sergey: How did you configure the PATH? Also, which Windows version is this?

Comment: @Sergey Please post your batch file, sometimes it can be as simple as adding "./" in front of the javac call (though that's a more *nixy solution)

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin; C:\MinGW\bin" this is what PATH variable holds

Comment: Give the source please, then we might see the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in space, no spaces between paths.